# Getting Facebook Like button to not show any image

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I was wondering if it is possible to have the post that the like button shows on the facebook feed not show any image but rather just a link like it used to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you can try setting your og:image meta take a blank image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.domains.com/img/spacer.gif" />
```

The test it here to see if it's being pulled properly: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/